# HIde HTML Elements Xamarin Android WebView?

Tags: c#, javascript, android, xamarin, wrapper

I am creating a web wrapper app, and am wanting to only show certain elements in an html page.  I have the current code below, and I know I need to use javascript possibly but am not sure where to go to from here.

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        var webView = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.webView);
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

        // Use subclassed WebViewClient to intercept hybrid native calls
        webView.SetWebViewClient (new WebViewClient ());

        webView.LoadUrl ("http://bobhoil.com/");

    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        base.OnCreateOptionsMenu (menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = this.MenuInflater;
        inflater.Inflate (Resource.Menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("your javascript");
webView.LoadUrl("javascript:" + sb.ToString());
```